# Rolling Rows in pandas.DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` that looks like this:

| year | month | valueCounts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 1 | 73.411285 |
| 2019 | 2 | 53.589128 |
| 2019 | 3 | 71.103842 |
| 2019 | 4 | 79.528084 |

I want `valueCounts` column's values to be rolled like:

| year | month | valueCounts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 1 | 53.589128 |
| 2019 | 2 | 71.103842 |
| 2019 | 3 | 79.528084 |
| 2019 | 4 | NaN |

I can do this by dropping first index of `dataframe` and assigning last index to NaN but it doesn't look efficient. Is there any simpler method to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe are already sorted.

Use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['valueCounts'] = df['valueCounts'].shift(-1)
print(df)

# Output
  year  month  valueCounts
0  2019      1    53.589128
1  2019      2    71.103842
2  2019      3    79.528084
3  2019      4          NaN
```